# How do I select a table row for an element I created dynamically with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am pulling data from a json file, looping through each object in that file, and adding a row with table data for each object.

Within my loop, I check whether each json object is null or not.

My goal is to make the null objects a different color than the non-null objects.

The problem is I cannot select (with css) each row in order to change the color. I can select `<td>` elements, and other elements, but not the `<tr>` elements.

The way I am creating the row seems to be causing problems. I've tried appending the row first then the `<td>`'s, and looked through stack overflow but haven't found anyone with a similar issue.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/jdagley77/pen/ZyNVOW/)

```js
var twitchJson = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/QuincyLarson/2ff6892f948d0b7118a99264fd9c1ce8/raw/e9e12f154d71cf77fc32e94e990749a7383ca2d6/Twitch%2520sample%2520API%2520responses%2520in%2520array%2520form?'

$.getJSON(twitchJson, function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    if (data[i].stream) {
      var tds = '<td><img src=' + data[i].stream.logo + '></td>' +
        '<td><a href=' + data[i].stream.url + '>' +
        data[i].stream.display_name + '</a>' + '</td>' +
        '<td class="status">' + data[i].stream.status + '</td>';
      var tableBod = $('tbody');
      $(tableBod).append('<tr> class="item">')
        .append(tds).append('</tr>')

    } else if (!data[i].stream && data[i].display_name) {

      var tds = '<td><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dtk22y6kq/image/upload/v1500593748/download_fi6yez.jpg" alt="image not available"></td>' +
        '<td>' + data[i].display_name + '</td>' +
        '<td class="status">This channel is currently unavailable</td>'
      var tableBod = $('tbody');
      $(tableBod).append('<tr> class="item">').append(tds).append('</tr>')
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#content {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#title {
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: darkblue;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Impact", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 15%;
}

tr {
  background-color: #8b8b00;
}

td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table {
  background-color: #ffd366;
}

.item {
  color: blue;
}

a {
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 20%;
}

.status {
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>Twitch Streamers</h1>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So your code could be a lot cleaner. Really the only thing you're doing is changing the td based on an if statement. I've consolidated a lot of repetition and made it a bit cleaner for you. Also, as @Mingle Li pointed out, your syntax for the tr wasn't correct either.

Check out this codepen and let me know if you have questions. All I changed was your js: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgQLVQ

```
$.getJSON( 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/QuincyLarson/2ff6892f948d0b7118a99264fd9c1ce8/raw/e9e12f154d71cf77fc32e94e990749a7383ca2d6/Twitch%2520sample%2520API%2520responses%2520in%2520array%2520form?', function( data ) {
    var $table = $( 'table' );

    for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        var $tr = $( '<tr class="item"></tr>' ),
            $tds;

        if ( data[i].stream ) {
            $tds = $( '<td><img src=' + data[i].stream.logo + '></td>' + '<td><a href=' + data[i].stream.url + '>' + data[i].stream.display_name + '</a>' + '</td>' + '<td class="status">' + data[i].stream.status + '</td>' );
        } else if ( !data[i].stream && data[i].display_name ) {
            $tds = $( '<td><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dtk22y6kq/image/upload/v1500593748/download_fi6yez.jpg" alt="image not available"></td>' + '<td>' + data[i].display_name + '</td>' + '<td class="status">This channel is currently unavailable</td>' );
        }

    // append the tds to your tr, then the tr to the table
        $tr.append( $tds );
        $table.append( $tr );
    }

} );
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to clean up my code. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect your table, you will find that your cells are not actually wrapped in `tr` elements.  That's because you are appending a `tr` element, and then appending the cells for that row.

To append the cells within the `tr` element, do:

```
$(tableBod).append('<tr class="item">' + tds + '</tr>')
```

And then you can add a class with which to easily target unavailable rows

```
$(tableBod).append('<tr class="item unavailable">' + tds + '</tr>')
```

```js
var twitchJson = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/QuincyLarson/2ff6892f948d0b7118a99264fd9c1ce8/raw/e9e12f154d71cf77fc32e94e990749a7383ca2d6/Twitch%2520sample%2520API%2520responses%2520in%2520array%2520form?'

$.getJSON(twitchJson, function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    if (data[i].stream) {
      var tds = '<td><img src=' + data[i].stream.logo + '></td>' +
        '<td><a href=' + data[i].stream.url + '>' +
        data[i].stream.display_name + '</a>' + '</td>' +
        '<td class="status">' + data[i].stream.status + '</td>';
      var tableBod = $('tbody');
      $(tableBod).append('<tr class="item">' + tds + '</tr>')

    } else if (!data[i].stream && data[i].display_name) {

      var tds = '<td><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dtk22y6kq/image/upload/v1500593748/download_fi6yez.jpg" alt="image not available"></td>' +
        '<td >' + data[i].display_name + '</td>' +
        '<td>This channel is currently unavailable</td>'
      var tableBod = $('tbody');
      $(tableBod).append('<tr class="item unavailable">' + tds + '</tr>')
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#content {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#title {
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: darkblue;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Impact", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 15%;
}

tr {
  background-color: #8b8b00;
}

tr.unavailable {
  background-color: #eee
}

.unavailable {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table {
  background-color: #ffd366;
}

.item {
  color: blue;
}

a {
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 20%;
}

.status {
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>Twitch Streamers</h1>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - makes perfect sense, and seems very obvious now that I see what to do with wrapping the tds!

Answer (score 0):

It's because:

1. You're appending `'<tr> class="item">'`, which is invalid syntax. Should be `$(tableBod).append('<tr class="item">')`.
2. When you append the `tr`, it automatically creates the end tag for you. Therefore, the `.append(tds)` will not work as you expect. It'll just append your `tds` at the end of the table, not the row.

What I did is instead create a `html` variable, which stores your HTML string that you want to append. Then I just did `$(tableBod).append(html)`.

New codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRxqEm

Answer (score 0):

you have invalid syntax in jquery, its not

```
$(tableBod).append('<tr> class="item">').append(tds).append('</tr>')
```

but

```
$(tableBod).append('<tr class="item">' + tds + '</tr>');
```

Comment: You have invalid syntax as well.